# Find P[X=6] on a lottery ticket problem

Tags: probability

Suppose that every month in the year I buy a lottery ticket and that each month I win a prize with probability 1/4.

Let X be the number of months that I win a prize.

What is the value of $P[X=6]$?

Would this be a binomial problem?

I am very confused on how to approach this problem. Any tips on how to solve it would be helpful.

Comment: Binomial distribution with $n=12$ and $p=1/4$.

Comment: Use the binomial distribution

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{12}{6}\cdot\left(\frac14\right)^{6}\cdot\left(1-\frac14\right)^{12-6}$$